Why is $D_i f = \frac{\partial f}{ \partial g_i}$ and not $\frac{\partial f}{ \partial x_i}$?
If $f: E \subset \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^s$ and $g: H \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$  is differentiable at point $a$, $g(a)=b$ and $g(H) \subset E$ then
$$D_j f(g(a))= \sum\limits_{i=1}^m D_i f(b)\cdot D_j g_i(a)$$
Why $D_i f = \frac{\partial f}{ \partial g_i}$ and not $\frac{\partial f}{ \partial x_i}$
I am not sure where this $g_i$ came from.

Chain rule for multivariable function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule.

Try thinking about this in terms of a funciton composition: $$\varphi = f \circ g.$$
Let's go through it one step at a time: since $g$ maps an $n$-dimensional vector into an $m$-dimensional space, you can think of it as:
$$
g\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\ x_2 \\ \dots \\ x_n
\end{array}\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
g_1(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \\
g_2(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \\
\dots \\
g_m(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)
\end{array}\right)
$$
Now, in this $m$-dimensional space, that takes these $m$ functions and maps them into $\mathbb{R}^s$. That could be put down the same way:
$$
f
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
g_1(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \\
g_2(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \\
\dots \\
g_m(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
f_1(g_1(x), g_2(x), \dots, g_m(x)) \\
f_2(g_1(x), g_2(x), \dots, g_m(x)) \\
\dots \\
f_s(g_1(x), g_2(x), \dots, g_m(x))
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where, of course, $g_i(x)=g_i(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$.
Now you just use the chain rule, the same way you do in univariable calculus.

$g_i$ is the i-th coordinate of $g(x)$ that lives inside the transient space $\mathbb{R}^m$
The sum  index for i is from 1 to m. This is a major hint.

I think this confusion is largely due to this notation being very ambiguous. Let's make some thing clear:

By $f\circ g$ I will mean the function $f\circ g:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^s$ defined by $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$ for all $x\in\Omega$, where $\Omega=\{x\in H:g(x)\in E\}$.

By $Dh(p)$ I will mean the total derivative of the function $h$ at the point $p$ (you can think of this as the matrix of partial derivatives).

By $\partial_jh(p)$ I will mean the partial derivative of $h$ with respect to the $j$'the variable at the point $p$.


We can then state the chain rule in two ways. The first one is as
$$D(f\circ g)(p)=Df(g(p))Dg(p)$$
for all $p\in\Omega$ such that $g$ is differentiable at $p$ and $f$ is differentiable at $g(p)$. Note that, written this way, we make it clear that $D(f\circ g)$ is the derivative of the composition of the two functions, while $Df$ and $Dg$ are the derivatives of the functions $f$ and $g$ by themselves. Indeed notice that $Df(g(p))$ means that we evaluate the function $Df$ at the point $g(p)$, and not that we differentiate the composition of $f$ and $g$.
Now if we wanted to write out the chain rule for partial derivatives, this would then read
$$\partial_j(f\circ g)(p)=\sum_{i=1}^m\partial_if(g(p))\partial_jg_i(p),$$
where we on the left hand side take the partial derivative of the composition $f\circ g$, and on the right hand side the partial derivatives of $f$ and the components $g_i$ of $g$, and never the partial derivative of the composition.
